# Can't run andEngine game on my phone

Tags: android, configuration, andengine

I have just created a small game in andEngine and I am unable to run it from eclipse on my HTC Rezound. I go to run configurations and the project does not show up. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: There is no way anyone can answer your question. There is simply not enough information. Explain steps that you have performed in order to run the app, post any problems from console and the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install 'intel X86' in the extras section in the SDK Manager . After installing 'intel X86' also if your system is showing problem such as "HXA not installed " , that means you have to check whether your system supports virtualization . Suppose your system doesnt support virtualization , then you can't run your game on emulator . Emulator requires virtualization enabled in the system .
If your system doesn't support virtualization , then You should run using real smart phone which has android OS in it to test your game.

stems If your system supports virtualization , then you have to enable virtualization to run your game on emulator . Virtualization(VT) is a hardware related thing. Some systems support virtualization some may not .